# Installation to specific user folder is changed to installation to the current user folder

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, shortcut-file

If (using Inno Setup) I install MyApp to C:\Users\User1\MyApp and create a shortcut on the public desktop. This shortcut correctly points to C:\Users\User1\MyApp\MyApp.exe on the desktop of User1, but it points to C:\Users\User2\MyApp\MyApp.exe on the desktop of User2!

I understand that creating a machine install in a User folder is asking for problems, but we are stuck with many customers who have exactly done that in the past (when we had a more or less per user installation). So how can I make the shortcut point to the Users\User1 folder for all users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my [lengthy](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=95841&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#95841) [replies](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=95842&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#95842) in the news groups.

In summary, User2 can not reliably access User1's profile, and it seems that Explorer is changing the target to suit. It may only do this if 1) it can't access the folder or 2) it's on a domain and assuming roaming profiles, but as it's undefined behaviour, it could do anything.

Your best bet is to stop it from installing into under c:\users (or the O/S equivalant).

If you have users will be upgrading from a "per user" install, you will need to use a different `AppID` so it doesn't attampt to upgrade the existing installation.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote a seperate Inno Setup script that copies the shortcuts to the `{userdesktop`} and `{userprograms`} and under the `[Run`] section I execute it with the `runasoriginaluser` Flag. The location of the executable is passed as a commandline parameter. Moreover I made the execution of this script dependent on the user's choice to make an instlallation only for himself (as opposed for all users).

Comment: It remains the responsibility of the user to only install to his own User folder when he means to have the application only available to himself.

Answer (score 2):

The better way is to install your application in drive `c:\program files\{your app folder}\{appname}.exe` or to any location except `{UserDesktop}`

Then using Inno Setup contants `{commondesktop}` instead of `{userdesktop}`, this will place your shortcut to `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` where all the users can see, even the new user create prior to installation can have it.

example

```
[Files]
Source: MyApp.exe; DestDir: {app};

[Icons]
Name: **"{commondesktop}\[You app Folder]**"; Filename: MyApp.exe; Tasks: desktopicon; IconFilename: MyApp.exe
```

OR IF YOU STILL INSISTS, use the following code

```
[Files]
Source: MyApp.exe; DestDir: {commondesktop};
```

Comment: Thanks for he comment. The problem is that we are stuck with users who already have installed to the Users folder. Now that we are migrating to a per machine installation this causes some headaches.

Comment: I've just added a note to my reply about handling upgrades.

Comment: Yes... it is a headache already and no easy task will do that..but to create patch application that automatically move your application properly, pls see my below remedy...

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you have to create new package and then Uninstall the previous, and use your new package to install it properly.
2. you have to manually move the application folder [C:\Users\User1\MyApp] to C:\Users\Public\Desktop, and delete the shortcut, then create new shortcut pointing to C:\Users\Public\Desktop\MyApp\MyApp.exe
3. Or by worst, change the security of folder [C:\Users\User1\MyApp] or User1 account to non-Private... so any user can access the folder... here are the links on how to do that
   a. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930987
   b. http://www.scribd.com/doc/101389/Password-Protecting-and-Privatizing-Windows-XP-User-Accounts

or search it using google or any search engine on how to remove privatized folder in xp

Comment: Thank you for thinking with me! 1.: No. Many users will want to keep their private copy of our App not trusting the other users ;-) The only problem with this arises with the shortcuts. The program itself is perfectly capable to peacefully co-exist with other versions, identical or not. 2. That seems a very strange place to put an executable. C:\Program Filles\OurApp seems the best spot for a shared installation and any other folder, the C:\Users folder included, is suitable for a private installation.  3. That hack should be avoided IMHO, but thanks for the link on how to do it.